# Find five friends to eat chicken with Paul

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Paul is one of your Belgian acquaintances, and he would like you to create a program that **outputs at least one of the following five strings**:

```
12496=>14288=>15472=>14536=>14264

14264=>12496=>14288=>15472=>14536

14536=>14264=>12496=>14288=>15472

15472=>14536=>14264=>12496=>14288

14288=>15472=>14536=>14264=>12496
```

It represents the friends he's most proud of, and he would like to eat with them. Paul also thinks that the number 6 is perfect, and that is the only number worth using. So **you cannot use any other digit than "6"** in your code (0 to 5 and 7 to 9 are forbidden). Your program cannot take any inputs. The output can contain garbage before and/or after the string but should contain at least one of the above strings.

For example this is a valid output :

```
220frefze
f**14288=>15472=>14536=>14264=>12496**fczfe fz**15472=>14536=>14264=>12496=>14288**zfe
fzehth
```

I "ligthly" hinted in the question as how I expect this to be resolved, but how knows ? Maybe there is a better way... Hope you have fun.

This is code-golf : lowest score in bytes wins.

Comment: Related [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A122726) sequence.

Comment: I can't figure out what Paul or chickens have to do with this.

Comment: @carusocomputing : The sociable chain '12496=>14288=>15472=>14536=>14264" was found by [Paul Poulet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Poulet), in 1918 (a belgian mathematician). And "poulet" means "chicken" in french. Also 6 is a perfect number in the sense that the sum of its divisor is 6.

Comment: Wait, so a manchicken found a sequence of numbers in 1918... and we care more about the number sequence than the mathematical manchicken named Paul?

Comment: I have a feeling my 4-byte answer isn't precisely what you were shooting for. Feel free to remove the garbage output rule.

Comment: @Dennis, well this is true, I was'nt expecting a bruteforce 4 byte answer, you're always a surprise :p  I added this rule because I was hoping to give an edge if someone was iterating over integers and outputing all found sociable chains without hard coding a complicated number first. But in the end it seem to favor greatly base conversion, and character conversion even in non golfy language. I think designing question is really hard ! Still, Enigma used the property of the output and has the higher score so far :)

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
•w[•Y·FDÑ¨O})„=>ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYVF5NJCIPLTdzeXwxEMr/Gs1HzXMs7U7vPf/fwA)

**Explanation**

```
•w[•                # base 214 encoding of 12496
    Y·F             # loop 2*2 times
       D            # duplicate top of stack
        Ñ           # push divisors
         ¨          # remove the last element (itself)
          O         # sum
           }        # end loop
            )       # wrap in list
             „=>ý   # join list on "=>"
```

In short, we calculate each number as `f(n+1) = sum(divisors(f(n)) - f(n)`

Answer (score 5):

### Pyke, 16 bytes

```
wヰw$VDlsh)J"=>
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=w%E3%83%B0w%24VDlsh%29J%22%3D%3E)

```
wヰ             -  12496
  w$            -   4
    V    )      -  repeat ^:
     D          -   duplicate(^)
      l         -     factors(^)
       s        -    sum(^)
        h       -   ^ + 1
          J     - v.join(^)
           "=>  -  "=>"
```

Anytime a string literal is at the end of a program, it swaps it with the token just before it, saving 1 byte in cases such as this. Pyke's `factors` function doesn't include the number itself nor 1. If numbers were allowed, 1 byte could be saved by replacing `w$` with `4`

### Pyke, 21 bytes

```
uバ㟐㱰㣈㞸J"=>
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=u%05%E3%83%90%E3%9F%90%E3%B1%B0%E3%A3%88%E3%9E%B8J%22%3D%3E&input=12496+14288+15472+14536+14264)

Create a list of the numbers required and joins them. Not very interesting apart from the trick with the strings.

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB, 44 bytes

```
['','=>@EBIJ=@>DDIJ=A@C>IJ=@A?BIJ=@>B@'-6-6]
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/#0vhvW)

I haven't found a pattern in the numbers (and it would be hard to use the pattern to anything anyways, since I can't use numbers), so I'll just go for the naive approach.

`'=>@EBIJ=@>DDIJ=A@C>IJ=@A?BIJ=@>B@'` is the string `'12496=>14288=>15472=>14536=>14264'` when 12 is added to the ASCII-values. Now, input that string, subtract `6+6`, and concatenate with the empty string `''` to convert it to a character array.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wanted to prevent the hard coding of number, but it's sure giving an edge to 'golfy' language. There is no pattern although each number is the sum of the divisor of the previous one.

Comment: I like the way the coded string still contains `=>`.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 57 bytes/47 (UTF-8) characters

*Thanks to user5090812 for 10 B save*

```
_=>[...'バ㟐㱰㣈㞸'].map(a=>a.charCodeAt()).join`=>`
```

### Explanation

First we create an array and fill it with the characters in the string `バ㟐㱰㣈㞸`. Then we loop over the string (`a` has the value of the current element) and we change the character into its character code. Then we join all values in the array by `=>`.

### Old: 67 bytes

```
_=>[6,6,6,6,6].map((_,a)=>`バ㟐㱰㣈㞸`.charCodeAt(a)).join`=>`
```

#### Explanation

First we create an array of length 5. Then we change the values of the array at each index for the character code of the character at that same index in the string `バ㟐㱰㣈㞸`, which are the numbers of all of Paul's friends in order. When we got that, we join the array together, and we use `=>` as separator.

### Usage

To use it, simply run this:

```
f=_=>[...'バ㟐㱰㣈㞸'].map(a=>a.charCodeAt()).join`=>`;alert(f())
```

### Output

```
12496=>14288=>15472=>14536=>14264
```

Comment: How about _=>[...'バ㟐㱰㣈㞸'].map(s=>s.charCodeAt()).join\`=>\`

Comment: @user5090812 Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 36 bytes (26 characters)

```
p"バ㟐㱰㣈㞸".unpack("U*")*"=>"
```

Because, why not. Boring as hell.

### older version - 53 bytes

```
p %w(jol mld oim n6b mke).map{|x|x.to_i ~-6*~-6}*'=>'
```

Explanation: encoding the numbers in base 25 gives the 5 six-free strings, to decode them I only have to represent the number 25 using only 6: (6-1)*(6-1) => ~-6*~-6

Comment: I count 36 bytes with UTF8, not 26.

Comment: I guess he counted the characters, and not the bytes. I always use [this](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) site for byte counts.

Comment: Corrected count now.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>63</s> 59 bytes

```
{$/=6;$/--;join "=>",<JOL MLD OIM N6B MKE>».parse-base($/*$/)}
```

```
{join "=>",<JOL MLD OIM N6B MKE>».parse-base(--($_=6)*$_)}
```

Decodes the numbers from base 25, because that's the only base supported by `.parse-base` (2 to 36) where none of them have invalid digits.

*Thanks to Neil for -3 bytes.*

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>82</s> 75 bytes

```
{my \a="BXS".parse-base(6*6);join "=>",(a,{sum grep $_%%*,^$_}...^{$_==a if $++})}
```

```
{my \a="BXS".parse-base(6*6);join "=>",({$/=$_//a;sum grep $/%%*,^$/}...a)}
```

Decodes the number `15472` in base 36, and then generates the sequence by calculating each number as the sum of proper divisors of the previous number.

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 69 bytes (47 characters) - noncompeting

```
{"{١٢۴۹6}=>{١۴۲۸۸}=>{١۵۴۷۲}=>{١۴۵۳6}=>{١۴۲6۴}"}
```

Doesn't use any of the forbidden ASCII digits, uses Unicode digits from the Arabic-Indic block instead (2 bytes each)! The `{ }` string interpolations make sure they're parsed as Perl 6 number literals, and then stringified to their ASCII representations.

Okay, this is cheating - that's why I didn't use it as my main answer... :)

Comment: Since I don't readily have access to a Perl 6 interpreter, does it work to write `--$/*$/`?

Comment: @Neil: It does. Thanks! In fact, it even works if I inline the assignment, like `--($/=6)*$/)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
ȷṗȷỌ
```

Prints all five strings. Takes advantage of the fact that "garbage" output is allowed and buries the five strings in **10<sup>3003</sup>** characters of output.

#### How it works

```
ȷṗȷỌ  Main link. No arguments.

ȷ     Set the return value to 1000.
 ṗȷ   Cartesian power; form all arrays of length 1000 that consist of integers in
      [1, ..., 1000].
   Ọ  Unordinal; convert all integers to characters.
```

Comment: What's the byte offset of the required string within the output?

Comment: Is there any proof to support any one of the required strings is actually printed?

Comment: @Neil The character offset should be **48049051056053060061048051049055055060061048052051054049060061048051052050053060061048051049053051000**. Not sure about bytes.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer If by *actually* you mean with reasonable time and memory constraints, then no. The challenge doesn't specify any limits though, and they're unlimited by default.

Comment: @Dennis No, I mean ever. Of course it's implied it won't finish its job anytime soon. Judging by the code, though, I think that it's really unlikely to ever print any of those strings. Then, again, I just thought of some reasonable proof...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer The proof is actually quite straightforward. The output contains *all* strings of length **1000** that consist of Unicode characters **1** to **1000**.

Comment: @Dennis Yeah, that's exactly what I thought of. The problem is, well, I'm not Dennis.

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>94</s> <s>84</s> 77 Bytes

Stoopid simple.  Special thanks @Neil

```
g(){char*m="!mnpuryzmpnttyzmqpsnyzmpqoryzmpnrp";for(;*++m;)putchar(*m-66+6);}
```

<s>f(){printf("%d=>%d=>%d=>%d=>%d",'~'*'r'-'d','~'*'d'-'h','~'*'r'-'L','~'*'z'+'d','~'*'t'-'P');}</s>

Comment: At least on ideone, you can move the `char*m` inside the `for()` to save a byte, and it also makes the function reusable (necessary condition of functions). Also, you output a trailing null; `*++m` would fix that. Also, you can save some bytes by subtracting 60 instead of 66: `g(){for(char*m="!mnpuryzmpnttyzmqpsnyzmpqoryzmpnrp";*++m;)putchar(*m-66+6);}`.

Comment: Or you could copy the approach from the MATLAB answer, which would save another byte on top of that.

Comment: @Neil my compiler won't let me declare inside of the for loop `initial declaration used outside C99 mode` but I'm happy to simplify the putchar.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>73</s> <s>63</s> 60 bytes

```php
for(;$c="|`*X6H-$*@"[$i];)echo!!$i&++$i?"=>".!!6:"",ord($c);
```

Run with `-nr`.

a little less lazy: took string as list of `=>1(ascii)(ascii)`
i.e.: `124`,`96`,`=>1`,`42`,`88`,`=>1`,`54`,`72`,`=>1`,`45`,`36`,`=>1`,`42`,`64`;
print `=>1` by string index, append ascii code

**breakdown**

```php
            # loop through string with index $i
for(;$c="|`*X6H-$*@"[$i];)echo
            # string ascii values: 124,96,42,88,54,72,45,36,42,64
    !!$i        # true if $i>0
    &++$i       # odd if (old) $i is 0,2,4,6,8
                # -> true for 2,4,6,8
        ?"=>".!!6   # if true, print "=>1"
        :"",        # else print nothing
    ord($c);    # print ascii value
```

Answer (score 1):

### C++, 92 bytes

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(){for(char c:"UVX]ZabUXV\\abUYX[VabUXYWZabUXVZX")putchar(c-6*6);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 53 bytes

```
<?=join('=>',unpack('v*',gzinflate('�`p������s')));
```

Hex dump:

```
00000000: 3c3f 3d6a 6f69 6e28 273d 3e27 2c75 6e70  <?=join('=>',unp
00000010: 6163 6b28 2776 2a27 2c67 7a69 6e66 6c61  ack('v*',gzinfla
00000020: 7465 2827 bb60 70c1 bcc0 e684 c50e 7300  te('.`p.......s.
00000030: 2729 2929 3b                             ')));
```

Output:

```
12496=>14288=>15472=>14536=>14264
```

Explanation:

Each of the five-digit integer sections is encoded as an unsigned short little endian, then concatenated together and the result is gzipped. This happens to produce a byte steam that has no offending digit characters, which is then hard-coded into a string. To extract, un-gzip the stream, unpack the two-byte shorts, interpret each as a string, and join with `>=`.

Comment: how about a breakdown?

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 134 bytes

Golfed:

```java
()->{String s="";for(String a:new String[]{"JOL","MLD","OIM","N6B","MKE"}){if(!s.isEmpty())s+=("=>");s+=Long.valueOf(a,25);}return s;}
```

Ungolfed, full program:

```java
import java.util.function.*;

public class FindFiveFriendsToEatChickenWithPaul {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(toString(() -> {
      String s = "";
      for (String a : new String[] { "JOL", "MLD", "OIM", "N6B", "MKE" }) {
        if (!s.isEmpty()) s += ("=>");
        s += Long.valueOf(a, 25);
      }
      return s;
    }));

  }

  private static String toString(Supplier<String> s) {
    return s.get();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 191 bytes

```
@set/as=n=66*(66+66+66+6*6)+66/6+66/6+6,u=6/6
@call:t
@call:t
@echo %s: ==^>%
@exit/b
:t
@call:c
:c
@for /l %%i in (%u%,%u%,%n%)do @set/an-=%%i*!(%n%%%%%i)
@set/an=-n
@set s=%s% %n%
```

I estimate that it would take a minimum of 32 bytes to calculate each number using only `6`s plus another 32 to print them all out, which is already 192 bytes, so I'm winning by computing the amicable chain. Also, I think five `%`s in a row is a record for me. Also, neat Batch trick: the `%n%` is substituted before the `for` loop is evaluated, so the loop calculates all the factors of `n`, and subtracts them from `n`, thus resulting in the negation of the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
“<ọ’ÆṣÐĿj“=>
```

Prints the fourth string and nothing else.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYY7Nw929jxpmHm57uHPx4QlH9mcBxWzt/v8HAA)

#### How it works

```
“<ọ’ÆṣÐĿj“=>  Main link. No arguments.

“<ọ’          Yield the 1-based indices of '<' and 'ọ' in Jelly's code page, i.e.,
              [61, 222], and convert the array from base 250 to integer.
              This yields 15472.
      ÐĿ      Iteratively call the link to the left until the results are no longer
              unique and return the array of all unique results.
    Æṣ        Compute the proper digit sum of the previous value (initially 15472).
        j“=>  Join, separating by the string "=>".
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, <s>78</s> 72 bytes

```py
print''.join(chr(ord(x)-6-6)for x in'=@>DDIJ=A@C>IJ=@A?BIJ=@>B@IJ=>@EB')
```

**Edit** - Thanks to [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31516/stewie-griffin) for saving 6 bytes!

Also, another solution would be to output all the possible permutations. OP says garbage is fine.

```
from itertools import permutations
print str(list(permutations(''.join(str(x)+'.'for x in range(int('9'*5)).replace(',','').replace('\'','') 
# also 9 and 5 need to be converted using ord and chr
```

There is too much redundancy in converting from `int` or `list` to `str`. I guess this would be easier in some esoteric languages, but I know none of them.

Comment: Could you add 66 instead of 12? This would save another byte.

Comment: It will go out of the normal ASCII-range @GB, meaning you would have to count two bytes per character.

Comment: I see, I didn't count the '=>' characters.